# How to use webpack-dev-server multiple entries point

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I would like to use the webpack-dev-server to host multiple entry points at one PORT. My current config is below:

```js
entry: {
    //Application specific code.
    main: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${config.HOST}:${config.PORT}`, 
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './app/base.js',
        './app/main.js'
    ],

    login: [
        `webpack-dev-server/client?http://${config.HOST}:${config.PORT}`, 
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './app/base.js',
        './app/login.js'
    ],
},
output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    publicPath: `http://${config.HOST}:${config.PORT}/public/dist/`,
    chunkFilename: "[name].js",
    filename: '[name].js',
},
```

But seems like it doesn't work for me right now. Any help?

Comment: I looking for the same thing. Any luck?

Comment: At this moment, I worked it around by creating a shaed `webpack.base.config` and for each entry point there is a `webpack.[some entry].config' which will use the base config from `webpack.base.config`. Not ideal, but works fine.

Comment: Sounds a very  good solution by now. I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of a working multiple entrypoint webpack config. Let me know if it helps.
I use `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),`  to generate a common.js file with the common js parts automatically.

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackErrorNotificationPlugin = require('webpack-error-notification')


var buildEntryPoint = function(entryPoint){
  return [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    entryPoint
  ]
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    search: buildEntryPoint('./src/index'),
    generic: buildEntryPoint('./src/index-generic')
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEV__: true,
      __DEVTOOLS__: true  // <-- Toggle redux-devtools
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'redbox-react': path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src')
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: is `webpack.DefinePlugin` necessary?

Answer (score 6):

A bit late response, but I had a similar problem, and solved by multiple `HtmlWebPackPlugin` plugin entries.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    root: ['./src/index.js'],
    labelling: ['./src/labelling.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
...
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html",
      chunks: ["root"]
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/labelling.html",
      filename: "./labelling.html",
      chunks: ["labelling"]
    })
  ],
...
```

Ref: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/218