# Vue JS Project with HTTP and HTTPS urls

Tags: vue.js, https, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I'm working with Vue JS using the webpack template, and dev mode.

How can I have part of my server using the HTTPS protocol and other part using HTTP?

I know that to use HTTPS is just add "https: true" to the devServer variable of the file build/webpack.dev.conf.js . Example:

```
devServer: {
    https: true,
    // other variables...
}
```

But when I do that just the HTTPS requests are accepted, no HTTP anymore.

How can I work with both protocols? If it's not possible, is there a VueJS way to redirect an HTTP request to an HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

It [doesn't look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644440/1585345) totally straightforward to configure multiple entry points on your webpack server. Your best bet is likely to reverse-proxy the http requests using whatever other webserver you have handy. IIS will do this for you, for example. Google "reverse proxy [name-of-your-webserver]" :-)